# Adding tags to S3 objects using awswrangler?

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, aws-data-wrangler

I'm using [awswrangler](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to write parquets in my S3 and I usually add tags on all my objects to access and cost control, but I didn't find a way to do that using directly awswrangler. I'm current using the code below to test:

```py
import awswrangler as wr
import boto3
import pandas as pd

# Boto session
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='my_profile')

# Dummy pandas dataframe
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

wr.s3.to_parquet(df=df_pandas, path='s3://my-bucket/path/', boto3_session=session)
```

There is a way to add tags to the objects that `.to_parquet` will write in my S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out that **awswrangler** has a parameter called `s3_additional_kwargs` that you can pass additional variables to the s3 requests that **awswrangler** does for you. You can send tags like in boto3 `'Key1=value1&Key2=value2'`

Below is an example how to add tags to your objects:

```py
import awswrangler as wr
import boto3
import pandas as pd

# Tagging
tag_set = 'Key1=value1&Key2=value2'

# Boto session
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='my_profile')

# Dummy pandas dataframe
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

wr.s3.to_parquet(df=df_pandas, path='s3://my-bucket/path/', s3_additional_kwargs={'Tagging': tag_set}, boto3_session=session)
```